# Peut-on dire «soulageante»?

Tags: vocabulaire, adjectifs, participe-présent, santé-et-médecine

Dans mes cours de médecine, on voit souvent la paire *soulageants*/*aggravants* en parlant de facteurs affectant une douleur. Je me demandais si on peut utiliser cette même paire au féminin. Or, en consultant le Multidictionnaire, le Trésor de la Langue Française et le Petit Robert, j'ai remarqué que «aggravant» est mentionné comme adjectif, mais pas «soulageant», qui est uniquement un verbe! Utiliser ce dernier au pluriel ou au féminin serait-il donc une erreur?

Toutefois, en cherchant sur Google, j'ai trouvé plusieurs articles qui utilisent «soulageant» comme un adjectif:

- [Victoire soulageante, mais peu convaincante](https://journalmetro.com/sports/349423/victoire-soulageante-mais-peu-convaincante/) (Métro, 26.06.2013)
- [Une victoire soulageante](https://www.journaldemontreal.com/2015/10/10/une-victoire-soulageante) (Le Journal de Montréal, 10.10.2015)
- <del>http://alterjournalisme.blogs.courrierinternational.com/archive/2016/02/21/resultat-du-caucus-du-nevada-clinton-marque-une-victoire-sou-51443.html</del>
- <del>http://fr.canoe.ca/sports/videos/victoire-soulageante-pour-francoise-abanda/5123712613001</del>
- [Soulageante médaille d'argent au relais féminin](https://www.ledevoir.com/sports/actualites-sportives/400274/charles-hamelin-victime-d-une-autre-chute-bete-au-500-metres) (Le Devoir, 10.02.2014)
- [Maux de tête: tension, mal de cou ou vraie migraine?](https://www.coupdepouce.com/sante-et-vitalite/sante/article/maux-de-tete-tension-mal-de-cou-ou-vraie-migraine) (Coup de Pouce, 29.10.2008)
- <del>http://www.lapresse.ca/le-droit/opinions/201705/09/01-5096382-a-vous-la-parole.php</del>

Je voudrais donc savoir s'il s'agit d'un usage fautif ou d'un usage correct qui n'est tout simplement pas reconnu dans les dictionnaires. Merci!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certainement pas une erreur, emploi tout à fait reconnu depuis longtemps.

> **« [soulageant », définition dans le dictionnaire Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/soulageant)**
>
> soulageant, ante
>   (sou-la-jan, jan-t') adj.
>
> Qui soulage.
>
> "Quelques personnes charitables de Grenoble ayant cru, à l'exemple de ce qui se pratique à Lyon, que ce serait une chose soulageante pour les pauvres…", [Boislisle, Correspond. contrôl. génér. p. 282, 1692]

Donc, le mot est employé depuis longtemps comme adjectif. Une recherche dans google books montre qu'il est beaucoup utilisé en médecine, par exemple :

> .. vomissements abondants, non soulageants (lavement avec 16 grammes de sulfate de soude, et le vin émétique trouble; eau vinaigrée en boissons). (*[Journal de pharmacie et de chimie](https://books.google.fr/books?id=srM8AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA158&dq=soulageants&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=soulageants&f=false)*, 1844)

> Comme c'est grâce à la doublure hallucinatoire de l'analyste que les transferts soulageants vers la parole se produisent... ([*Actualités de la psychanalyse*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=epcoDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT676&lpg=PT676&dq=soulageants&source=bl&ots=7OMe7J8eUa&sig=bVQ6jspYRRdn81Ri7AZBAGc9AnU&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4s_v84anUAhVpDsAKHTgeBPQQ6AEIXTAO#v=onepage&q=soulageants&f=false), Gisèle CHABOUDEZ,CLAIRE GILLIE, 2014)

Mais pas seulement en médecine :

> Notre manifestation quotidienne, multipliée, donne cette sensation, en l'occurrence, soulageante. (*[La Nouvelle nouvelle revue française](https://books.google.fr/books?id=9nsYAQAAIAAJ&q=soulageante&dq=soulageante&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y)* - Numéros 64 à 66, 1958)

> Dan et son groupe étaient sans doute rentrés se coucher ; les prix Pulitzer partis écouter du jazz, nous restions seuls au beau milieu de la rue Petronia à nous faire des confidences chuchotées, maladroites mais combien soulageantes. ([*Le gay savoir*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Nd8cAQAAIAAJ&q=soulageante&dq=soulageante&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y), Michel Tremblay, 2005)

> Surprenante et soulageante découverte. Bilan carbone nul ! Cela mériterait un reportage. [*(EcoAmerica : Voyage en quête de solutions durables*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=zaobCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT153&dq=soulageante&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=soulageante&f=false), Guillaume Mouton, 2015)

Et voici je pense pourquoi il ne se trouve pas dans la majorité des dictionnaires :

> *Soulageant* : Invariable comme verbe, variable comme adjectif verbal. Ce dernier cas n'est pas indiqué par l'Académie. La plainte 'soulageant la douleur. Des paroles *soulageantes*. Des remèdes *soulageants*. (*[Le véritable manuel des participes ou dictionnaire grammatical et usuel des participes français](https://books.google.fr/books?id=y5Y-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA439&dq=soulageants&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=soulageants&f=false)*, BESCHERELLE, E. 1856)

Un oubli de l'Académie Française ! Mais l'Académie Française n'est que l'Académie Française, la langue est une chose vivante, qui bouge, qui évolue, et l'emploi de soulageant comme adjectif ne s'usera que si l'on ne s'en sert pas.

Je termine par encore une citation, cette fois-ci de [*Enrichissement de la langue française ; dictionnaire des mots nouveaux*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=USVbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA554&lpg=PA554&dq=soulageant%20%22Enrichissement%20de%20la%20langue%20fran%C3%A7aise%20;%20dictionnaire%20des%20mots%20nouveaux%22&source=bl&ots=PD9QAcMNsp&sig=DX2V6DShl5C1OQipBMXl4WO_WPM&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi25u2P5KnUAhWNbFAKHZAaDcUQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=soulageant%20%22Enrichissement%20de%20la%20langue%20fran%C3%A7aise%20%3B%20dictionnaire%20des%20mots%20nouveaux%22&f=false), J. B. Richard de Radonvilliers, 1845 :

> Soulageante, adj.; qui soulage, qui cause, opère un soulagement : ce remède est soulageant.

Comment: **«luy appliquer des remedes soulageants la douleur»** me semble être davantage un participe présent accordé (peut-être suivant une ancienne coutume) qu'un adjectif...

Comment: Un bien étrange « soulageants la douleur » qui est forcément un participe présent en ne peut s'accorder ainsi en français moderne.

Comment: Certes, mais du moment qu'il est accordé c'est un adjectif, non ?  mais bon si vous pensez que c'est une faute de frappe, je peux enlever cet exemple, c'est le français qui me plaisait... snifff

Comment: Je crois qu'il demeure possible d'utiliser une entourloupe quelconque pour préserver la citation, mais ce n'est sûrement pas un adjectif (remplacer par un autre adjectif pour s'en convaincre: luy appliquer des remedes bleus la douleur).

Comment: @Feelew J'en ai trouvé une autre (ce n'ai pas ce qui manque...) qui fera tout aussi sourire j'espère.

Comment: Pour l'accord historiques des participes présents, LBU§922 pour la 14e édition (sûrement près de là dans les éditions rapprochées, sinon l'index à participe présent suffira à rapidement retrouver l'article en question).

Answer (score 5):

Nombre de participes présents sont devenus adjectifs lorsque le besoin s'en fit sentir. Il fut vraisemblablement un temps pour chacun d'eux où la forme adjectivale fut nouvelle, possiblement contestée. Si l'usage l'adopte, tôt ou tard la norme doit lui faire une place ou perdre sa crédibilité.

L'adjectif *soulageant* est-il utile en médecine ? Je dirais que oui.

Est-il nécessaire à la société en général ? Peut-être pas, mais si on l'expose suffisamment à la tournure, elle pourrait très bien décider que c'est un outil qu'elle adoptera.

Y aura-t-il des grincements de dents ? Probablement, mais ce n'est pas ce qui compte à la fin¹.

Le mot final de ceci reviendra néanmoins à Laure, qui a tracé un grandiose historique de l'utilisation de l'adjectif *soulageant* et a démontré hors de tout doute qu'il a déjà traversé des siècles. Malgré sa relative discrétion et l'ignorance que lui montrent certains dictionnaires, il a survécu et est bel et bien vivant aujourd'hui.

> ¹ Par exemple, je n'aime pas l'adjectif *sociétal* et m'abstiens de l'utiliser, ce qui ne m'empêche pas de le rencontrer ici et là. Je ne saurais commencer à blâmer tous ceux qui l'utilisent, car ça me priverait de discuter avec eux et je suis certain que le contenu de leurs messages vaut bien que je n'accorde pas trop d'importance à l'antipathie que je porte à un seul mot, voire à une expression.

Answer (score 1):

Je dirais que c'est un usage fautif : le mot soulageant n'étant qu'un participe présent du verbe soulager, il est invariable et donc ni soulageante ni soulageants ne sont des mots français.

Bonne journée.